# pytest_sessionstart/finish show AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'results'

Tags: python, pytest

In pytest, I want to collect all test results and trigger some function after all tests done. My pytest version is 6.2.5. Therefore, I prepared the confest.py as below.

```
def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    print("session start")
    session.results = dict()

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    result = outcome.get_result()

    if result.when == 'call':
        item.session.results[item] = result    
   
@pytest.hookimpl(trylast=True)
def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    print()
    print('run status code:', exitstatus)
    passed_amount = sum(1 for result in session.results.values() if result.passed)
    failed_amount = sum(1 for result in session.results.values() if result.failed)
    print(f'there are {passed_amount} passed and {failed_amount} failed tests')
```

However, when I ran the pytest, it always show me the following errors.

```
INTERNALERROR>   File "conftest.py", line 143, in pytest_runtest_makereport
INTERNALERROR>     item.session.results[item] = result
INTERNALERROR> AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'results'


File "conftest.py", line 149, in pytest_sessionfinish
passed_amount = sum(1 for result in session.results.values() if result.passed)
AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'results'
```

May I ask what could be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I think I found what is wrong. pytest_sessionstart must be put in the confest.py at the root folder instead of the subfolder. Otherwise, it can not be executed to add results attribute.

Answer (score 1):

pytest_sessionstart must be put in the confest.py at the root folder instead of the subfolder. Otherwise, it can not be executed to add results attribute.